# Can a graph be a subgraph if each component is not connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Say you two connected components of G. Can they be "combined" as one subgraph with no edges connecting them?

Comment: What do you mean by "combined"? I think an example would be helpful here.

Comment: If you’re asking whether, for instance, `*--*  *` is a subgraph of `*--*  *  *`, the answer is *yes*.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A graph $G'=(V',E')$ is a subgraph of a graph $G=(V,E)$ whenever $V'\subseteq V$ and $E'\subseteq E$.

There are no further conditions as to the connectivity of subgraphs or anything else beyond what is written above.  Also, note that a graph is always a subgraph of itself.  Subgraphs need not be proper.

Alternatively, one can see a graph $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$ if there exists a sequence of deleting edges and deleting vertices (along with any remaining edges which would have used the deleted vertices) that transforms $G$ into $G'$.